# how add pagination with ng-repeat directive in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

in my current project i need to add the pagination on `ng-repeat` directive in **angularjs** i tried but affecting the filter on `ng-repeat.`

so suggest me smarter way to develop pagination in angularjs it also include sorting and filter.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You may have a method that gets specific data from the server: getData(from, size). This way you'll receive exactly (i.e) 30 items (size) to display on page 1. Then for page 2 you'll call getData(30, 30)then (60, 30) and so on. You can filter and sort items on every page.

Your routes may look like this: myList/2, myList/$pageNumber - so you'll know the params to call getData($pageNumber*30, 30).